# Symfony, how tu create a firewall authenticator without any provider

Tags: php, security, symfony

I just want to have a service that filters the requests (I don't have tokens, nor Users, nor DB, etc)

For example if it includes the header "xxxxx" with the value "yyyyy" the request would continue to the controller, if not, it should return a 401 Response.

I can create a listener with that service, and subscribe it to the "kernel.controller" event and verify the last mentioned rule.

But I want to know if I can do this with the security bundle, that allows me to only apply it to desired URLs, etc

Comment: Sounds like some sort of API type authentication - I could swear there's an example of something like this in the Symfony2 docs, probably the cookbook. Either way, have a read about Security Voters, which might help you out.

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/api_key_authentication.html

Answer (score 0):

simply add a SecurityListenerFactory to the securityContainer:

```
/**
 * Class AppBundle
 *
 * @package AppBundle
 */
class AppBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        parent::build($container); 

        $extension = $container->getExtension('security');
        $extension->addSecurityListenerFactory(new MySecurityFactory());
    }
}
```

create a custom security factory:

```
/**
 * Class MySecurityFactory
 *
 * @package AppBundle\DependencyInjection\Security\Factory
 */
class MySecurityFactory implements SecurityFactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @param ContainerBuilder $container
     * @param string           $id
     * @param array            $config
     * @param string           $userProvider
     * @param string           $defaultEntryPoint
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function create(ContainerBuilder $container, $id, $config, $userProvider, $defaultEntryPoint)
    {
        $listenerId = 'security.listener.'.$id;
        $listener = $container->setDefinition($listenerId, new DefinitionDecorator('security.listener.'));

        return array($providerId, $listenerId, $defaultEntryPoint);
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPosition()
    {
        return 'pre_auth';
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getKey()
    {
        return 'my_secret';
    }

    /**
     * @param NodeDefinition $node
     */
    public function addConfiguration(NodeDefinition $node)
    {
    }
}
```

and create a custom Listener:

```
/**
 * Class MySecurityListener
 *
 * @package AppBundle\Security\Firewall
 */
class MySecurityListener
{
    /**
     * @param GetResponseEvent $event
     */
    public function handle(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();

        try {
            // do things you like
        } catch (AuthenticationException $failed) {
            // ... you might log something here
        }

        // By default deny authorization
        $response = new Response();
        $response->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
        $event->setResponse($response);
    }
}
```

but I recommend to use for example a preAuthToken or similiar.

Hope that helps.